# How to incorporate macroeconomic factors in the Dynamic Nelson Siegel model?

Tags: r, kalman-filter, state-space

I am having a hard time adding macroeconomic variables to the Dynamic Nelson Siegel codes I found online. I read literature like Diebold et al. (2003): The Macroeconomy and the Yield Curve: A Nonstructural Analysis and Diebold et al. (2005): The macroeconomy and the yield curve: a dynamic latent factor approach. They mention to merely include the macroeconomic variables in the state vector and expand the VAR coefficients matrix, the vector of means, and the variance-covariance matrix of the disturbance terms. But I am not sure how to translate this into code. Can anyone help? I am very confused. I also do not know how the data should look like.

[This](https://github.com/ZheHuang96/Master-Thesis-Code) is one of the codes I saw from Zhe Huang's "Fitting Yield Curve with Dynamic Nelson-Siegel Models: Evidence from Sweden" and also [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/statespacer/vignettes/selfspec.html) using the `statespacer` package in R.

Any help would be appreciated as I do not have a lot of guidance from supervisors and I am only a beginner coder. I am currently using Rstudio. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.